# problem to get auto-incremented primary key with hibernate / postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, primary-key

Using hibernate 5.4, postgres 10 with IntelIiJ Ultimate,  impossible to get auto-incremented primary key

with this following code, the sequence "warehouses_id_seq" is created but the primary key is not incremented

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "warehouses")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQUENCE_WAREHOUSE", sequenceName = "warehouses_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
public class Warehouse implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQUENCE_WAREHOUSE")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
```

Comment: how does the SQL look like?

Comment: hibernate generates this script :

Hibernate: create table warehouses (id int4 not null, address varchar(255), gps varchar(255), name varchar(255), business_id int4, organization_id int4, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create sequence warehouses_id_seq start 1 increment 1

plus other lines related to @ManyToOne declarations

Comment: and how does the Insert statements look like? Do you see the increment of the sequence?

Comment: we should get this line :  <  alter table warehouses alter column id set default nextval('public.warehouses_id_seq'); >

Comment: if I try an insert I get this error message :  <  [23502] ERREUR: une valeur NULL viole la contrainte NOT NULL de la colonne « id » >

Answer (score 0):

I added below line to fix the problem:

```
@ColumnDefault("nextval('public.warehouses_id_seq')");
```

But I'm quite desapointed, I expected Hibernate to do it automaticaly with the `SequenceGenerator`...